# Remove attribute of parent only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to remove the href attribute of the first link, at the moment it removes the attribute of ALL the links.

```
$("#menu-item-2003 a").removeAttr('href');
```

This is my html setup:

```
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the `href` of the first `a`, use [direct descendent](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector:

```
$("#menu-item-2003 > a").removeAttr('href');
```

The one which you use currently allows selection of the children at any level, which was causes the issue.

Working demo:

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 > a").removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Alternatively, if `a` is not a direct descendent, you can use the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo class to select the very first tag:

```
$("#menu-item-2003 a:first").removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `first()` in jquery

```
 $("#menu-item-2003 a").first().removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With First

- Using [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a").removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a").first().removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

- Using first [:first Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a:first").removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a:first").removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

- Using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a Selector

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a").filter(":first").removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a").filter(":first").removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

---

#### With eq

- Using [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a").eq(0).removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a").eq(0).removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

- Using first [:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a:eq(0)").removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a:eq(0)").removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

- Using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a Selector

  ```
  $("#menu-item-2003 a").filter(":eq(0)").removeAttr('href');
  ```

```js
$("#menu-item-2003 a").filter(":eq(0)").removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2003">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="menu-image-title">Products</span>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2005">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2006">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="icon.svg">
        <span class="menu-image-title">Title</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```